# Wait for a request to finish before doing another one in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

```
    A.Add1()
        .success(function (response) {
            alert("add1");
        }).
        error(function (response) {
            alert("error in add1");
        });



    A.Add2()
        .success(function (response) {
            alert("add2");
        }).
        error(function (response) {
            alert("error in add2");
        });
```

I need to do two requests one by one. But sometimes the second one is being done before the first one. How do I prevent this in angularjs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
   A.Add1()
    .success(function (response) {
        alert("add1");
        A.Add2().success(function (response) {
            alert("add2");
          }).
           error(function (response) {
            alert("error in add2");
           });
      }).
    error(function (response) {
        alert("error in add1");
    });
```

Nested promise

**PS:** `.success` is deprecated. Prefer `.then()`.

Comment: Thanks. I was confused by having told to use " $q " on the internet.

Answer (score 2):

For easier way, you can execute the `A.Add2()` inside of the success function `A.Add1()`.

Example as below:

```
    A.Add1()
        .success(function (response) {
            alert("add1");

            A.Add2()
            .success(function (response) {
                alert("add2");
            }).
            error(function (response) {
                alert("error in add2");
            });
        }).
        error(function (response) {
            alert("error in add1");
        });
```